# Running SSIS Package from WinForms app - Gnarly Error

Tags: c#, winforms, ssis

I have a winforms application that makes use of `Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS` to load and execute an SSIS package. When running locally in debug and when installed the package runs fine, when installed on a dev server the package runs fine. When deployed onto a live server I get the following error.

[image: Error Message]

I'm running out of  ideas of what to check, I don't want to move away from using this method of executing my package as this adds further complication to the application that we really don't want to introduce. Any thoughts?

For clarity I have checked:

- SSIS is installed and is the same version (Windows/SQL Server 2008)
- I added the following app.config key following some google searching `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"`
- Tried compiling as a 32-bit and 64-bit application
- Ensured that the DLL is registered in the GAC on the target machine
- All permissions are the same across the two boxes

The extract of source code that is throwing the error is as follows:

```
var app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
var pkg = app.LoadPackage(strSSISPath, null);
pkg.ImportConfigurationFile(strSSISConfig);

var result = pkg.Execute();

if (result.Equals(DTSExecResult.Success))
{
    string strMsg = strMHType + " extract completed successfully.";
    MessageBox.Show(strMsg, strMHType, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
else
{                         
    foreach (var err in pkgMHMDS.Errors)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Description, strMHType, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    MessageBox.Show(strMHType + @" extract failed!", strMHType, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
pkgMHMDS.Dispose();
```

Comment: What line is throwing the error? I assume that's from the pkgMHMDS.Errors collection but want to verify. What is the package doing? Do you have custom components, either homebuilt or third party, in the packages? What happens if you just run the package once from the command line on that server? Where do strSSISPath and strSSISConfig point to? Are they on the local file system or a network path. What about the account running this app: does it have sufficient permissions to access everything?

Comment: The exception is thrown on the very first line `(var app =...)`. The package is picking up records from a SQL database and inserting into an access db. Running the package manually, from the command line using DTEXEC and the GUI are all fine. I have run under an admin account also but with the same error

Comment: Just to verify, when you ran dtexec, did the second line say `Version 10.50.xxxx.0 for XX-bit` or `Version 10.00.xxxx.0 for XX-bit` and was it the same across both servers? Since it's throwing the error on the instantiation of the Application, it smells like there is something going on with the references to the assemblies.

Comment: Just checked and I used Version 10.10... on both servers. It must be something to do with the reference to the DTS assembly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that we see (the COM class error) is caused because the version of the Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS dll is not installed on the target machine. Whilst we did install the dll into the GAC we couldn’t work round the error because Integration Services is a server component and is not redistributable to client computers. The error isn’t terribly informative but essentially what it is trying to say is that it is trying to load an assembly who’s address is stored in the registry key which is created when installing the Client Tools SDK.